# Navigation / toolbar buttons stop working after keyboard is shown on iOS 17 - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am facing a strange issue that seems to be happening on iOS 17 but the same thing works fine in iOS 16.

I have a `QLPreviewController` wrapped in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. The goal is to load a PDF in a SwiftUI view so this is why I take this approach.

I don't think this is where the issue lies but here is the code for completeness

```
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook

struct QLPDFPreviewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        return navigationController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController,
                                context: Context) { }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate {
        let parent: QLPDFPreviewController
        
        init(parent: QLPDFPreviewController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController,
                               previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            guard let url = parent.url else { return NSURL(string: "")! }
            return url as NSURL
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController,
                               editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
            .updateContents
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController,
                               didUpdateContentsOf previewItem: QLPreviewItem) {
            print("did some updates")
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController,
                               didSaveEditedCopyOf previewItem: QLPreviewItem,
                               at modifiedContentsURL: URL) {
            guard let url = parent.url else { return }
            try? FileManager.default.moveItem(at: modifiedContentsURL, to: url)
            print("moved")
            print()
        }
    }
}
```

This is my swiftUI view:

```
struct QLPDFView: View, KeyboardPublishing {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State private var showingPreview = false
    
    @StateObject var pdfViewerViewModel: PDFViewerViewModel
    
    @State private var shouldShowCancelAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if pdfViewerViewModel.formMode == .edit {
            content
        } else {
            NavigationStack {
                content
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var content: some View {
        ZStack {
            if pdfViewerViewModel.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                QLPDFPreviewController(url: pdfViewerViewModel.pdfFileURL)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            saveNavBarItem
                                .bold()
                        }
                        
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                            cancelNavBarTitle
                                .alert(isPresented: $shouldShowCancelAlert) {
                                    Alert(title: Text("Warning"),
                                          message: Text("Do you want to overwrite?"),
                                          primaryButton: .cancel(Text("Stay")),
                                          secondaryButton: .destructive(Text("Leave")) {
                                        pdfViewerViewModel.shouldSaveData = false
                                        dismiss()
                                    })
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            pdfViewerViewModel.configure()
        }
    }
    
    private var saveNavBarItem: some View {
        return AnyView(Button(action: {
            dismiss()
        }, label: {
            Text("Save")
        }))
    }
    
    private var cancelNavBarTitle: some View {
        return AnyView(Button(action: {
            shouldShowCancelAlert = true
        }, label: {
            Text("Cancel")
        }))
    }
}
```

The issue that I face in iOS 17 is that when the keyboard opens up, for some reason the toolbar buttons at the top and in the navigation bar stop working which the rest of the UI is still operational.

The above code can be seen working here in this [video](https://youtu.be/wIittW_RIcs) which is on iOS 16.

However, the same code, when running on iOS 17, you can see the toolbar buttons are no long functional once the keyboard is open - here is the [video](https://youtu.be/pmcIUky9-Iw)

**Update**

I feel this could be a bug related to the `QLPreviewController` in iOS 17 and it has something to do with the `UINavigationController` the `QLPreviewController` is wrapped in.

If I remove the `UINavigationController` when creating the `QLPreviewController`, this issue disappears. However, the downside of that is, all the controls like drawing, sharing etc also no longer appear with a UINavigationController.

I tried doing this purely in UIKit and could reproduce the issue and also gave the [solution mentioned here](https://nilcoalescing.com/blog/PreviewFilesWithQuickLookInSwiftUI/) a try, however, this didn't work as well.

Another hint into something to do with iOS / Navigation stack is this warning that appears in the console:

`Could not update done button menu because it was not found #PreviewController`

Usually a `done` button comes with `QLPreviewController` if you open a PDF in the mail app for instance, however, this does not happen when using the `QLPreviewController` in SwiftUI.

Comment: Try putting the NavigationStack outside the if/else

Comment: @loremipsum - this view can be presented or pushed. In the case it is pushed, we already have an existing navigation stack. If it is presented, that is when I need the navigation stack. This is why I need it to be inside the if/else

Comment: @loremipsum - I tried your suggestion just to test if this would work. It didn't. I think this is an iOS 17, QLPreviewController issue because the same issue occurs when I do this purely in UIKit